# Kotlin / IntelliJ - Compiler cannot find correct parameter type of function

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm writing a code in **Kotlin** language *(of JetBrains)* using **IntelliJ** and i'm facing a error on compiler where the compiler cannot find the correct parameter type of a function, always saying that the function receve a **`Nothing`** parameter.

Someone have any idea of what is the problem?

[Print Screen showing the error on IntelliJ IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49f0O.png)

In the image, the console show the compiler error, but a help on center of the screen shows that IntelliJ can find the correct parameter type of the function, but compiler not.

==== Edited ==========================================

The Java code is:

```
  @Transactional
  public int deletar(BuscaInfo info) {

    // ----  Criando a busca ao banco:
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaDelete query = cb.createCriteriaDelete( info.classe );
    Root root = query.from( info.classe );

    // Cláusula WHERE do banco:
    Predicate[] preds = WhereBuilder.build(cb, root, info.where);
    if (preds.length < 1) {
      throw new MsgException(JsonResponse.ERROR_EXCECAO,null,"Os parâmetros de filtragem da QueryString não são válidos.");
    }
    query.where(preds);


    // A busca ao banco:
    int qtd = em.createQuery(query).executeUpdate();
    return qtd;
  }
```

and `info.classe` is of type `Class<?>`.

Using Hibernate 5.x and JPA 2.1 api to compile.
That code works on WildFly 9.x and 10.x.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please check the type of `q` variable? (navigate to it, the run alt+q)
I suppose its type is `CriteriaDelete<*>`, and none of these `from` methods can be called for the same reasons they can't in Java on a variable of type `CriteriaDelete<?>`: we can't say exactly what `T` was there when the instance was created.

But diagnostic, of course, could be better here. I've created [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16779) on this

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
Yes, the `q` variable is `CriteriaDelete`, but this code is a rewrite of a Java code i have, and in Java i call this `.from( Class<?> )` method of `CriteriaDelete` and `CriteriaUpdate` (not post about, but i have same issue with `CriteriaUpdate`). If i not call this method, an exeception is thrown saying that root need to be specified. Thanks to open an issue  =D

Comment: It's very strange, that it works in Java. Can you please share the relevant Java version?

Comment: Edited the question adding the piece of code write on Java.Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a tricky moment in your Java code: you use raw type `CriteriaDelete query` that effectively turns off exact type matching when calling `from` on it. If you use `CriteriaDelete<?>` type instead you will get a similar error.

In Kotlin there are no raw types, but you always can use unsafe cast like
`(q as CriteriaDelete<Any>).from(info.classe as Class<Any>)` that would be a fair Kotlin version of your Java code